# Display new attribute in related Products

Tags: related-products

I have a new attribute,
and I want to display the new attributes, those related to the product, why this code does not work ?? What is wrong?

```
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getData('condition')) ?>
```

why, to display the SKU, this works?

```
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getsku()) ?>
```

Comment: attribute type??

Comment: I do not know
attribute type ?? What is that?

but I add atrubute of:
Catalog> attribute> attribute Manage attribute.

and I want to display it in the block related product.

Answer (score 1):

As `$item` is object of class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Link that why you cannot get condition field value from $item .`If  `condition` is `a product attribute` then you need to `get Product object  from  $_item`.Usually `getProduct()` is given you the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Object`.Using this you `can get this attribute value`

**See code:**

```
$_product=$_item->getProduct();

  $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('condition')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can I know the explanation?
Why double?
and how to make foreach?

```
<?php
$_product = $this->getProduct();

if($this->getItems()->getSize()){


$related_prods = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('condition')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',array('in'=>$_product->getRelatedProductIds()));

    foreach($this->getItems() as $_item){

        foreach($related_prods as $related){
?>
            <li class="item col-lg-12 border-ngisor">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                <?php if(!$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox related-checkbox" id="related-checkbox<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" name="related_products[]" value="<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" />
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="product">
                    <a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getsku()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'thumbnail')->resize(50) ?>" width="50" height="50" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" /></a>
                    <div class="product-details">
                        <p class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a></p>
                        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true, '-related') ?>
                        <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_item) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <?php echo $related->getData('condition'); ?>
                </div>
            </li>
<?php
        }
    }
}
?>
```

SS:
[image]